# Data Gridview in asp.net using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have two gridview in two different tr and td,i want to display one of them by setting visibility true or false but when i run it though only one is visible but the position of gridview remains static as it should be placed on the top which is not happening.Help me out

[image]

Comment: Please post some of the code

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you use a table to show these grids? If I have understood you correctly, you need the bottom grid to take the space above, if the top grid is not visible. I strongly recommend not to use a table for this, but relative positioned divs. If you MUST use a table, use javascript to resize your top row, when needed.

Comment: thanx a lot, it helped